# What is the error in a below written php source code for drop down list of date of birth?

Tags: php, html, web, calendar, date

I am trying create login web page.This is the code written to display drop down list for date of birth.But I am not getting day and year in the drop down list. Please guide me in this.

```
 <select class="biginput" name ="day">
    <option> Day </option>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
          {
              echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
          }
    ?>
</select>
<select class="biginput" name="year">
    <option>Year</option>
    <?php for($i=date("Y");$i>=date("Y")-90;$i--)
              echo"<option value=$i>$i</option>";
    ?>
</select>
```

Output: I am getting only blank list instead of days and year.
[image: Output]

Comment: This code sample works as expected, the select elements are populated

Comment: Can you view the source of the HTML to check if the options are there (you should also enclose any attributes in quotes).

Comment: Are you sure your PHP server is up ?

Comment: Select lists work for me.  Try testing any Php: `<?php echo  'hello Earth'; ?>` does that output?  Failing that, disable your style sheet/javascript.

Comment: @ XavierBrt I got it.I was trying with login.html instead of login.php. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ XavierBrt Thank you so much